# How to see this assertion about coordinate rings and a localisations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, localization, toric-geometry

I am studying 'The Homogeneous Coordinate Ring of a Toric Variety' by David Cox, and in the proof of his theorem 2.1 he defines
$U_\sigma := \{x\in \mathbb{C}^{\Sigma(1)} : x^{\hat{\sigma}}\neq0\}$
where ${\Sigma(1)}\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x^{\hat{\sigma}}$ is a monomial in the ring of polynomials $S:=\mathbb{C}[x_i|i=1,..,{\Sigma(1)}]$

The proof then states 'the coordinate ring of $U_\sigma$ is equal to the localisation of $S$ at $x^{\hat{\sigma}}$. Why is this the case? I have tried looking at the equivalence relations that define the coordinate ring and this localisation but I cannot see the connection.

Comment: What do you know about basis scheme theory? In general, if $f\in A$, then the coordinate ring of the open subscheme $D(f)\subset Spec(A)$ defined by the equation $f\neq 0$ is the localization $A_f$.

Comment: I haven't looked far into scheme theory, is this a fairly fundamental fact?

Comment: One of the most basic ones, it's basically how you define the scheme structure of $Spec(A)$.